# Чтение выборки из БД и обновление данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net, ms-access

Есть некоторая БД, которую я получаю запросом.

Я могу одновременно читать результаты выборки, вносить корректировки и что бы эти данные сразу же отправлялись на сервер?

Или я явно должен делать UPDATE ?

Comment: Наверное через DataAdapter можно. Неявно. Лучше попробуй EF

Comment: У меня Access БД...

Comment: Тогда только через DataSet

Answer (score 0):

Только Update, у реляционных Баз Данных существует такое понятие как транзакционная целостность, именно она не дает изменять данные на лету, поэтому это возможно только в рамках одного запроса.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду - "изменять данные на лету"?

Comment: Когда сразу после изменений данных в интерфейсе программы, происходит изменение данных в БД.